# how to insert one dataframe into another pandas that have different shapes

Tags: pandas

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["A","B","C","D"],
                   "B":[1,np.nan,np.nan,4],
                   "C":[1,456,5464,4],
                   "D":[1,234,9876,4],
                   "E":[1,2,3,4],
                   "F":[1,2,3,4],
                   "G":[1,2,3,4],
                   "H":[1,2,3,4]
                  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[9,10],
                   'col2':[11,12],
                   'col3':[13,14]})
```

df
[image]

df2
[image]

I want to put df2 `into` df1 so to say.

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":["A","B","C","D"],
                   "B":[1,9,10,4],
                   "C":[1,11,12,4],
                   "D":[1,13,14,4],
                   "E":[1,2,3,4],
                   "F":[1,2,3,4],
                   "G":[1,2,3,4],
                   "H":[1,2,3,4]
                  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[1:1+df2.shape[0], 1:1+df2.shape[1]] = df2.values
print(df)

# Output
   A     B   C   D  E  F  G  H
0  A   1.0   1   1  1  1  1  1
1  B   9.0  11  13  2  2  2  2
2  C  10.0  12  14  3  3  3  3
3  D   4.0   4   4  4  4  4  4
```

Note: `df2.values` convert dataframe as numpy array so you remove the row and column indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `loc` and find the entries that are `NaN`:

```
df.loc[df['B'].isnull(), ['B', 'C', 'D']] = df2.values
```

`df` is now this:

```
   A     B   C   D  E  F  G  H
0  A   1.0   1   1  1  1  1  1
1  B   9.0  11  13  2  2  2  2
2  C  10.0  12  14  3  3  3  3
3  D   4.0   4   4  4  4  4  4
```